# Tests on Sencha Touch

Tags: testing, sencha-touch

Does anyone know if there is a JavaScript test suite for testing Sencha Touch Apps like there is QUnit for jQuery.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/), it seems to be successful for many:
http://jonathangrimes.com/2011/10/jasmine-extjs-mvc-a-love-story/

*Soon* Sencha will be updating [Siesta](http://www.sencha.com/blog/introducing-siesta-a-testing-tool-for-ext-js/) to support Sencha Touch